# Return a value from an event?

Tags: c#

So, I have an event called `CalculateNewHeight`, which I've attached to an `action` called `OnHeightDataLoaded`:

`renderer.OnHeightDataLoaded += ((heightData) => CalculateNewHeight(heightData, instance));`

...but ideally at this point in the code it'd return a value, rather than just call another function, for example:

`int newData = renderer.OnHeightDataLoaded += ((heightData) => CalculateNewHeight(heightData, instance));`

Obviously that code's wrong, but you get what I mean. Using the event more like  async `await`. Is that possible?

Haha, I'm quite new to C#, so don't hesitate to let me know if I'm going about this all wrong.

Comment: You're thinking about this incorrectly.  An event is a way for your object to report to the world that it has done something.  It doesn't care whether there is one listener, no listeners, or many listeners - that's not it's responsibility.  If you're interested in the result of the registered thing then I'd suggest that you should pass that thing in to your object as a dependency on your object, and call a method on that dependency that can obviously return a value.

Comment: @LordWilmore, that's not completely true. .Net sometimes use events to "get a result" (sort of) from the notified client: take as example the [KeyPress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(v=vs.110).aspx) event and the Handled property of KeyEventArgs: the sender check the value of `e.Handled` set by the client, and if true it actually "swallows" the key. I agree that is not a good practice in general, considering that sender code should be agnostic to the number o client that subscribed the event.

Comment: @GianPaolo that's a good point.  Thanks for making it.

Comment: Haha, I swear SO is the only place on the internet you get such friendly disagreements.  Cheers guys, makes a lot of sense.